# Email Server IP Address is Blacklisted

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, blacklist, zimbra

we have a Zimbra Mail server that was being used for 2 months now.
the last week we faced a problem that the Public IP that was being used for our mail server started to be blacklisted and we couldn't send emails to many other domains.

we found that the Engineers who was responsible for Administrating our Public IP Block didn't configure a reverse DNS PTR.

we have changed the Public IP to another new one, we were able to send to some of the domains that we were blocked at but some others are still blocking, for example we can't send to gmail even that after we configured the New IP and Publish the new DNS reords we were able to send to gmail , but after 1 hour gmail bloked us again with this error message
The mail system

> : host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.67.26]
>   said:
>       550-5.7.1 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized
>       to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay
>       at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at
>       550 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=10336
>       ey7si20778000wib.30 (in reply to end of DATA command)

also below are some other errors we recieve from different domains

> The mail system
>
> : host maila.aljazeera.net[213.130.112.86] said:
>   550
>       5.7.1 Recipient not authorized, your IP has been found on a block list (in
>       reply to RCPT TO command)

---

> : host
>       relais-ias89.francetelecom.com[193.251.215.89] said: 550 5.7.1
>       : Client host rejected: Your message was rejected due
>       to spam filtering. Please see
>       http://www.sophos.com/security/ip-lookup?ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (in reply to RCPT
>       TO command)

any help or suggestion please, and can you please direct us to a place where we can learn how to make our server less likely to be blacklisted.

thanks

Comment: If that `41.78.60.33` is accurate, you still have no reverse DNS.

Comment: no, we changed that to new one but with the same subnet

Comment: Did you follow the links in the error messages you got? They should provide explanations.

Comment: and the new IP address has a reverse DNS entry? If it does, does it match the DNS record name?

Comment: yes it does match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMail and others will frequently blacklist a block of IP addresss in addition to the IP they are blocking. Getting an IP address white listed by Google, Yahoo, etc. is a tedious and slow process. And it is different for each email provider.

Here are links to the 4 major email providers mailing guidelines:

- http://postmaster-us.info.aol.com/Postmaster.Guidelines.php
- https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126
- http://mail.live.com/mail/policies.aspx
- http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/basics/postmaster-15.html

Comment: This sounds more like a comment?

Answer (score 4):

Tighten the config, make sure it's not relaying, and clean everything up.

Then contact the blacklist sites and have them retest.

That's really all you can do, find who's blacklisting you after cleaning things up and contacting them to re-evaluate your site and be taken off the lists.

Answer (score 4):

Blacklisting can be tested (and monitored for free) here: http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/blacklist.aspx?st=BL. Just make sure to check both your domain and IP.